# Renaming multiple files using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, rename, mv

I have downloaded multiple files from different s3 buckets to a single folder on a linux vm. I want to rename only the `*.gz` files in the directory, preferably sequentially, using a script to something like `FILE001_$(date '+%Y%m%d').csv.gz`,`FILE002_$(date '+%Y%m%d').csv.gz` etc, before moving them to client's sftp server(existing process).

I tried using `find . -name "*.csv.gz" -exec mv {} FILE%03d_$(date '+%Y%m%d').csv.gz` from another post but get `missing argument to -exec` error. Any examples using `rename` or `mv` for the above task please?

Comment: Please show us your own attempt, and clarify what didn't work. For more info about asking a good question, please see our [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -i i=0
for f in *.csv.gz; do
  : $((i++))
  mv "$f" "$(printf "FILE%03d_%s.csv.gz" $i "$(date +%Y%m%d)")"
done
```

You can pass the names of the files into the script. In that case you have to use `dirname` to get the name of the directory of each file.

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -i i=0
for f in "$@"; do
  : $((i++))
  mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")"/"$(printf "FILE%03d_%s.csv.gz" $i "$(date +%Y%m%d)")"
done
```

Example:

```
$ mkdir {1,2,3}
$ touch {1,2,3}/{a,b,c}.csv.gz
$ ./rename.sh {1,2,3}/*.csv.gz
$ ls {1,2,3}
1:
FILE001_20211012.csv.gz  FILE002_20211012.csv.gz  FILE003_20211012.csv.gz

2:
FILE004_20211012.csv.gz  FILE005_20211012.csv.gz  FILE006_20211012.csv.gz

3:
FILE007_20211012.csv.gz  FILE008_20211012.csv.gz  FILE009_20211012.csv.gz
```

Comment: That works like charm, thanks! How would I modify the above to run from a different path to where the files are, or run this across multiple directories please?

Comment: You can do `((i++))` which is simpler

Comment: @CMR H : If you want to run for different directory simply may it as a generic function and pass the path at run time to the script which ceving as provided